# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '60,72,64,50'

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

Here's my code:

```
from micromlgen import port
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename

def load_features(folder):
    dataset = None
    classmap = {}

    for class_idx, filename in enumerate(glob('%s/*.csv' % folder)):
        class_name = basename(filename)[:-4]
        classmap[class_idx] = class_name
        samples = np.loadtxt(filename)
        labels = np.ones((len(samples), 1)) * class_idx
        samples = np.hstack((samples, labels))
        dataset = samples if dataset is None else np.vpstack((dataset, samples))
    return dataset, classmap

from sklearn.svm import SVC

features, classmap = load_features('dataset/')
X, y = features[:, :-1], features[:, -1]
classifier = SVC(kernel="linear").fit(X,y)
```

I have no idea why it's giving out this error :(

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Luigie/PycharmProjects/STARK/Kobe.py", line 20, in <module>
    features, classmap = load_features('dataset/')

  File "C:/Users/Luigie/PycharmProjects/STARK/Kobe.py", line 12, in load_features
    samples = np.loadtxt(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Luigie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1159, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):

  File "C:\Users\Luigie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1087, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]

  File "C:\Users\Luigie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1087, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Luigie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 794, in floatconv
    return float(x)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿69,75,63,54'
```

Comment: Hey Ralph, to make this question a lot easier, could you include where it went wrong please?

Comment: Well, what float do you expect that string to parse to? Or do you think that the program is trying to parse the wrong string? Please give more details about the specific problem and expected behaviour.

Comment: At a guess... I suspect it's `samples = np.loadtxt(filename)` and it should be `samples = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')`

Answer (score 0):

Since the input file is a CSV and by default `loadtxt` of `numpy` module has a default value of the parameter `delimiter` as `None`, It is better to use the delimiter as ',' (i.e comma). In order to make it clear I have shared the documentation of the loadtxt function of numpy module.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> help(np.loadtxt)
Help on function loadtxt in module numpy:

loadtxt(fname, dtype=<class 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, ndmin=0, encoding='bytes', max_rows=None)
    Load data from a text file.

    Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : file, str, or pathlib.Path
        File, filename, or generator to read.  If the filename extension is
        ``.gz`` or ``.bz2``, the file is first decompressed. Note that
        generators should return byte strings for Python 3k.

   ...
   ...

    delimiter : str, optional
        The string used to separate values. For backwards compatibility, byte
        strings will be decoded as 'latin1'. The default is whitespace.

   ...
   ...
```